# Llenar una lista con contenido de una Api

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Estoy tratando de llenar una lista de personajes provenientes de una Api, pero tengo una duda de como lleno el array, he tenido dificultades de solo tener 10 personajes y que de estos se vean en una lista y generen un link a una película.
Hasta ahora tengo la llamada de  la API, pero solo me imprime el Json en la consola, habiéndole creado conexión con el html

```
function ajax_get(url, callback) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            console.log('responseText:' + xmlhttp.responseText);
            try {
                var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            } catch(err) {
                console.log(err.message + " in " + xmlhttp.responseText);
                return;
            }
            callback(data);
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

ajax_get("https://swapi.co/api/people/", function(data) {

    var html = "<h2>" + data["title"] + "</h2>";
    html += "<h3>" + data["description"] + "</h3>";
    html += "<ul>";
       for (var i=0; i < "https://swapi.co/api/people/10"; i++) {
           html += '<li><a href="' + data["people"][i]["name"] + '">' + data["people"][i]["mass"] + "</a></li>";
       }
    html += "</ul>";
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = html;
});
```

Agradezco la atención

Comment: Visitando la URL que usas, https://swapi.co/api/people/, creo que no estás respetando la estructura del JSON: los datos están anidados en el campo `results`, que es un array de elementos. No hay `people`, ni `title`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La verdad que deberías revisar bien que es lo que querías, había muchas cosas que no tienen sentido, por un lado estas intentando leer propiedades del `json` que te devuelve la `api` que no existen, deberías revisar la estructura, y luego tienes un `for` cuya condición es que un numero sea menor que un `string`, que no tiene ningún sentido.

Te he hecho ciertos cambios en el código y te los he ido comentando, échale un ojo.

```js
function ajax_get(url, callback) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    
            try {
                var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            } catch(err) {
                //console.log(err.message + " in " + xmlhttp.responseText);
                return;
            }
            callback(data);
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

ajax_get("https://swapi.co/api/people/", function(data) {
    
    //La llamada a la api, te devuelve un json con un atributo "results" que es donde vienen los personajes en forma de array, los guardamos en una variable
    var persons=data.results;
  
    //La propiedad data["title"] no existe en el json que recibes
    //var html = "<h2>" + data["title"] + "</h2>";
    var html = "<h2>Lista de personajes</h2>";
    //La propiedad data["description"] tampoco existe en el json que recibes
    //html += "<h3>" + data["description"] + "</h3>";
    html += "<h3>Esta es mi lista de personajes personalizada</h3>";
    html += "<ul>";
       //Este for no tiene sentido, estas haciendo un bucle en el cual la condicion es que un numero sea menor a un string, lo que debes hacer es recorrer el array de persons que hemos creado mas arriba
       //for (var i=0; i < "https://swapi.co/api/people/10"; i++) {
       for(var index in persons){
          //Recojemos cada personaje
          let person=persons[index];
          //Lo añadimos a la variable html sus datos
          html += '<li><a href="' + person.url + '">' + person.name + "</a></li>";
       }
    
    html += "</ul>";
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = html;
});
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="text"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Buenas, yo también veo cosas raras en la función `ajax_get` y en el bucle for cuando llamas a la función. Te dejo una aproximación, ojalá te sirve de ayuda. En el `console.log` comentado verás lo que te devuelve el server

Saludos

```js
function ajax_get() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open('GET', 'https://swapi.co/api/people/', true);
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
      if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
        getResult(xmlhttp);
      }
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function getResult (xhr) {
  var array = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
  //console.log(array);

  for (var i = 0; i < array.results.length; i++) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    document.body.appendChild(p);
    p.innerText = i+1 + '.- ' + array.results[i].name;
  }
}

ajax_get();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nose si lo he entendido bien pero igual lo que te falta es recorrer el Json e ir leyendolo.

```
$.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
});
```

[Aquí puedes encontrar la solución mas detallada](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), sino te vale necesito que me des mas información sobre tu problema.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esta linea no es correcta:

```
for (var i=0; i < "https://swapi.co/api/people/10"; i++)
```

estas condicionando un integro con una cadena de texto, si no me equivoco `for (var i=0; i < "https://swapi.co/api/people/10"; i++)` no hace nada tal y como está en ese momento.